# How to jump back to netrw when splitbelow is on

Tags: vim, netrw

If I open a file in a current directory using netrw and then reopen the netrw using `:Sexplore` the netrw window opens below (I have `splitbelow` set), but the cursor remains in the file being edited and I cannot move to the netrw window using `CTRL-W` combinations.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Steps to reproduce

- run `vim .`
- *netrw opens*, highlight a file in the **current** directory (let's say test.txt) and press Return, *file test.txt opens*
- run `:Sexplore` cmd
- netrw opens **below** but the cursor remains in the file opened previously.

My `.vimrc`

```
set nocompatible
set splitbelow
```

VIM version

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Dec  8 2015 23:11:08)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-944
```

This is how it looks like:[image: vim error]

Comment: I can reproduce it here, from my point of view, it is a bug.

Comment: I had this issue, 7.4.979 but once I upgraded to 7.4.1129 its gone.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce with version 154a (use `:echo g:loaded_netrwPlugin` to check your netrw version).

Try with [the latest version](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW).

---

**Edit:**

It is possible that the problem is cause by some other plugin interference or settings. You could try following the approach described at [Vim FAQ 2.5](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5):

> 2.5. I have a "xyz" (some) problem with Vim. How do I determine it is a
>        problem with my setup or with Vim?  / Have I found a bug in Vim?
>
> First, you need to find out, whether the error is in the actual
>   runtime files or any plugin that is distributed with Vim or whether it
>   is a simple side effect of any configuration option from your .vimrc
>   or .gvimrc. So first, start vim like this:
>
> ```
> vim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE
> ```
>
> This starts Vim in nocompatible mode (-N), without reading your
>   viminfo file (-i NONE), without reading any configuration file (-u
>   NONE for not reading .vimrc file and -U NONE for not reading a .gvimrc
>   file) or even plugin.
>
> (...)
>
> If the error does not occur when starting Vim this way, then the
>   problem is either related to some plugin of yours or some setting in
>   one of your local setup files. You need to find out, what triggers the
>   error, you try starting Vim this way:
>
> ```
> vim -u NONE -U NONE -N
> ```
>
> If the error occurs, the problem is your .viminfo file. Simply delete
>   the viminfo file then. If the error does not occur, try:
>
> ```
> vim -u ~/.vimrc --noplugin -N -i NONE
> ```
>
> This will simply use your .vimrc as configuration file, but not load
>   any plugins. If the error occurs this time, the error is possibly
>   caused by some configuration option inside your .vimrc file. Depending
>   on the length of your vimrc file, it can be quite hard to trace the
>   origin within that file.
>
> The best way is to add :finish command in the middle of your .vimrc.
>   Then restart again using the same command line. If the error still
>   occurs, the bug must be caused because of a setting in the first half
>   of your .vimrc. If it doesn't happen, the problematic setting must be
>   in the second half of your .vimrc. So move the :finish command to the
>   middle of that half, of which you know that triggers the error and
>   move your way along, until you find the problematic option. If your
>   .vimrc is 350 lines long, you need at a maximum 9 tries to find the
>   offending line (in practise, this can often be further reduced, since
>   often lines depend on each other).

Obviously you will have to load netrw manually (which can be done by sourcing plugin/netrwPlugin.vim -- if you are using some plugin manager you will have to move the plugin to ~/.vim/ or change your runtime path due to the autoload functions) and set `nocompatible` and `splitbelow`.

Actually there is an adapted version of this procedure in `:help netrw-debug`:

> Step 2: assuming that you've installed the latest version of netrw,
>   check that your problem is really due to netrw.  Create a file called
>   netrw.vimrc with the following contents:
>
> ```
> set nocp  
> so $HOME/.vim/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
> ```
>
> Then run netrw as follows:
>
> ```
> vim -u netrw.vimrc --noplugins [some path here]
> ```
>
> Perform whatever
>   netrw commands you need to, and check that the problem is still
>   present.  This procedure sidesteps any issues due to personal .vimrc
>   settings and other plugins.  If the problem does not appear, then you
>   need to determine what setting in your .vimrc is causing the conflict
>   with netrw or which plugin.
>
> Step 3: If the problem still is present, then get a debugging trace
>   from netrw:
>
> (...)

Comment: After updating to 155f it still doesn't work. Do you have `splitbelow` enabled?

Comment: @MaciejWozniak yes, I had the `splitbelow` enabled. Is there any chance it is plugin interference? I've included that on the answer.

Comment: Thanks @mMontu but it didn't help :(. What I did was: remove (backup) `~/.vim/`, `.vimrc`, `.viminfo`, then create a new `~/.vim/` with only latest netrw installed, and empty `.vimrc` with only `nocompatible` and `splitbelow` set. Same problem :(. What OS are you using? Maybe it's Mac-related.

Comment: Tried applying your latest solution (netrw.vimrc) - still no success. While reproducing this issue are you starting vim by `vim .` ? And is the file you're editing in the current directory ?

Comment: @MaciejWozniak I'm on linux, maybe it is Mac-related. And yes, I started with `vim .` and edited a file on the same directory. You should follow the third step on `:help netrw-debug` and open a bug, the plugin author usually answers very fast.

Comment: I just tried this with a mac using both vi (huge, v7.4.663) and mvim (7.4.258) along with netrw v155g, and was unable to duplicate the issue.  I used the -u netrw.vimrc approach.